# Why is my deployed rails app writing to a production.log file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Where in my configuration does it say to write to a production.log file?

What is the best practise for this, to log critical errors only I'm guessing, how would I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default the log file is a convention from the environment name. So in production environment the log will be named production.log, in development it is called development.log.

You can override the log file name and the log level for production in `config/environments/production.rb` by putting the lines below.

```
config.log_level = :error # this will the rails to log error only in production
config.log_path = log/something_else.log # defaults to log/#{environment}.log
```

Comment: so by default it logs w/o telling it to? my production.rb has all of this commented out.

Comment: Un-comment it to see the changes in effect.